# Is there a quick way to reverse selected excel cells?

Tags: excel, reverse

I want to know if there are any quickest way to reverse the selected excel cells?[Cell Reversing Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTXLP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,8-ROWS($A$2:A2))
```

Here, `$A$2:$A$8` is your data range, `8` is number of rows your data is in excluding header.

[image]

Got this from [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/19/reverse-a-list-in-excel/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this by creating a numerical index similar to below and then sort by the numerical index using Excel sort option.

[Sort option in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LdzB.png)